# MySQLi Login - Get no errors but nothing happens

Tags: php, mysql

I'm almost sure that the following line is wrong:

```
if ($mQuery){
```

But since num_rows won't work, I'm using it.
If the condition is wrong, what should I change it for?
My PHP login code:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","myUser","myPass","myDB");
    $error = false;

    $mQuery = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '.$mysqli->real_escape_string(md5($_POST['usuario'])).' AND  senha = '.$mysqli->real_escape_string(md5($_POST['senha'])));

    if ($mQuery){
        $mAjax = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) and strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
        if ($mAjax)
        {
            header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
            header('Expires: '.date('r', time()+(86400*365)));
            header('Content-type: application/json');

            echo json_encode(array(
            'logged' => !$error
            ));
            exit();
        }
        elseif (!$error)
        {
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: nothing should happen if $mAjax === false or $mQuery === false...also what doyou mean num_rows won't work?

Comment: But the login info is right, also when I use num_rows I get the error 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your query from

```
$mQuery = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '.$mysqli->real_escape_string(md5($_POST['usuario'])).' AND  senha = '.$mysqli->real_escape_string(md5($_POST['senha'])));
```

to

```
$mQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '" . 
          $mysqli->real_escape_string(md5($_POST['usuario'])) . 
          "' AND  senha = '" . 
          $mysqli->real_escape_string(md5($_POST['senha'])) . "'");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've forgot the quotes :P

Comment: You're certainly welcome. I'm glad it helped. On a side note you can benefit from using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)